# RESTful web services - for large requests

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, soap, jax-rs

Tech Stack: Java 1.6, JPA (Hibernate 3), Spring 3, Oracle 11g

Hello,

In one of my projects, we have to create a number of web services.
These web services are like 'create application' and 'udpate application'.

For creating an application, the input data (request XML) is around 90-100 lines.

In my view I should be using SOAP\XML webservice (Spring), but my company has decided to go forward with REST (JAX-RS).

I think it will be difficult for client to create such request without any formal contract.

Or do you think REST will serve the purpose?

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 1):

REST is much more flexible then SOAP. with REST service you can return responses as XML/JSON/HTML while in SOAP its usually just XML.

REST also uses plain HTTP unlike SOAP which extends HTTP.

So your company did the right choice. Regarding the format of the answer, if it's JSON, you can use libraries like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert messages. You'll need to write a document describing the different links and their input/output (look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline) for example)

If it's XML, all you need is an XSD for the request/response and again use a FW like [XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) to Marshal/Unmarshal the request/response. In that case, just give the client the XSD's and the above mentioned document.

Comment: thanks, I thought that the conversion from\to JSON\XML happens automatically if gson\jackson is on the classpath?? Why do I need xmlbeans??

Comment: You only need it if you don't use any rest framework, if you do, the xml to object conversion would be done by the framework. Conversion is not done automatically for json.

Comment: You can use JAXB annotations to automatically generate the response frm your POJO in the required format.